# Why can't a mutable method be called on a mutable String reference but works for TcpStream

Tags: rust

As I was trying to understand the differences between a mutable variable, which happens to be a reference, e.g. `let mut x: &i32` vs mutable references, e.g. `let x: &mut i32`, I found this difference I can't understand:

This works, where `by_ref` has the signature: `fn by_ref(&mut self) -> &mut Self` ([docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/net/struct.TcpStream.html#method.by_ref))

```rust
fn example(mut t: &TcpStream) {
    t.by_ref();
}
```

But the following with `String`, using a method with a similar looking signature, [`reserve`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html#method.reserve):

```
pub fn reserve(&mut self, additional: usize)
```

But this does not work, the error is:

> "cannot borrow `*str` as mutable, as it is behind a `&` reference"

```rust
fn example(mut str: &String) {
    str.reserve(10);
}
```

Interesting to note that these two examples with mutable references work, and are, as far I know, the recommended way to use mutable methods:

```rust
fn example_stream(t: &mut TcpStream) {
    t.by_ref();
}

fn example_string(str: &mut String) {
    str.reserve(10);
}
```

So what is different between a `TcpStream` and a `String` that allows methods with a `&mut self` argument to be called in one case and not in the other?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `TcpStream` sample is misleading you.

There is [`impl Read for TcpStream`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/net/struct.TcpStream.html#impl-Read) as you've linked to, but there is also [`impl Read for &TcpStream`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/net/struct.TcpStream.html#impl-Read-1). You are actually using the latter which does not need mutable access to the `TcpStream`, only mutable access to the *reference* to the `TcpStream`, which is `t`.

This is done because the `Read` trait uses mutable methods to allow readers that need mutation or exclusive access to read. However `TcpStream` actually doesn't need mutation or exclusive access to read data since it essentially just defers to a syscall. Because of this, `TcpStream` can be more flexible and allow multiple threads to read/write from a socket by implementing `Read` on its reference.

The `str.reserve()` call, on the otherhand, does not have this luxury and requires mutable access to the `String` itself, and thus a `&String` is not enough.

Comment: Fantastic, thank you so much, I had a hunch that it had something to do with implemented traits but could not figure out, and had no idea that traits could be implemented on the reference type as well, this is a perfect answer, thanks again!